# Chart Legend not showing, if Chart is an object, in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I'm making a Web App using ExtJS and Sencha Architect, and I'm showing data through graphs.

I encountered a weird behaviour. I have a Pareto and a Column Chart, and I promoted one them to classes. I then made instances of that charts in a floating panel.

It looks like this in the Design View:

[image: Design View]

The chart above is the class one, the one below was a copy of the class (instead of being linked). As you can see, the legends are visible in the Design View.

However, when I ran the code and previewed it, only the chart below, the one copied, was the only one with a visible legend, as can be seen here:

[image: Actual View]

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

I don't understand as to why a Chart that is a Class won't show the legend if it's linked, but if you copy it instead, it works.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle replicating your problem?

Comment: I think you have to add margin or something between the panels. I think the top legend is pushed down. Can you copy the code of your class?